# Is there a way to `return`, `break`, `cycle`, or `stop` on GNUPLOT?

Tags: gnuplot

I am writing a script that is creating multiple plots and movies from a very big bunch of data. However, sometimes I don't need the whole analysis and I want to limit myself to parts of the analysis. Just to know,

Is there a way to `return`, `break`, `cycle`, or `stop` on gnuplot?

Comment: perhaps the `exit` statement is what you are after?

Comment: Gnuplot iteration commands (`do for {}`, `while {}`) provide `continue` and `break` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exit` statement is straightforward and can be used anywhere in the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
nmin = 1
nmax = 10
nmiddle = (nmin + nmax)/2
isexit = 0
print "---------------------------------"
print "--------- REGULAR OUTPUTS -------"
do for[i=nmin:nmax]{
    print sprintf("Running No %4d", i)
}

# if (isexit==1){
#     print "here"
#     exit
# }


print ""
print "---------------------------------"
print "--------- EXIT OUTPUTS -------"
do for[i=nmin:nmax]{
    print sprintf("Running No %4d", i);
    if (i == nmiddle){
        exit 
    } 
}
```

For `break` and `continue`, it seems they are new features on GNUPLOT 5.2 and above as you can see in Page 21 (see [memo](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf)), and are explained on page 71 and 73 (see [memo](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf)).

I have GNUPLOT 5.0 right now. I will just have to upgrade it to version 5.2 and that's it.

Thanks Ethan and EWCZ.